# c++ pointer assignment in 64bit

Tags: c++, pointers, 64-bit, forward-declaration

I am trying something like this

```
//A.h
class P;

class A
{
  A(P* pp) { p = pp; }
  P* p;
};
```

```
//B.h
#include "P.h"

class B : public A
{
   B(A* aa);
};
```

```
//B.cpp
B::B(P* pp) : A(pp)
{}
```

the problem is that when for example

```
pp = 0x00000000024af3f0
```

but after the assignment

```
p = 0x024af3f0cdcdcdcd
```

this happens only in 64bit. also if I dont use the forward declaration of P there is no problem. and also if I do p = pp; in B's constructor there is no problem.

Comment: So, just to get this right: after the assignment, the pointer is not the same as the value you wished to set?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard for you to transform the code snippets provided into a complete self-contained minimal example that exihibits the problem at your side, and that we can take and compile and look at at our side.

Comment: What's in `p.h`, and how does this compile since neither `b.h` nor `b.cpp` include `a.h`?

Comment: @Amichai you should post your actual code. Aside from the mistakes in the made-up example the error is probably not in the parts that you posted.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. What compiler an which architecture are you using?

Comment: There is constructor of `B` that takes a pointer to `A` in `B.h` file, but in cpp, you construct `B` with a `P*`. What is your point? I bet the problem is here. You do not initialize the pointer. `B(A* aa) : A(aa->p) { }`. Do you have something like this?. Also this will lead to the question, who will deallocate the pointer `p`.

Comment: Does `B`'s constructor take a `P*` or an `A*`? Your code seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: Are you compiling it for 64bit or 32bit? p = 0x024af3f0cdcdcdcd indicates that the bottom 4 bytes are unitinitailised, this
 suggests that a 64bit pointer is assigned from 32bit one.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That would not have been possible here given the problem the guy actually had was a kind that resists binary chop.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if you forget to re-compile one of the source files after adding data to `class A`. The offset of `p` changes (in your case, by four bytes), but only one of the source files knows about it. Recompile everything and try again.